# Многопоточность и утечка памяти java

Tags: java, многопоточность, память

Подскажите пожалуйста как справиться с утечкой памяти или более решить задачу.

Раз в секунду получаю из базы значения, которые необходимо обработать
Полученный массив данных и обрабатываю отдельными потоками, что бы не затормаживать процесс:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{
@Override
public void run(){
    Map<Integer, MyObject> ar = new HashMap();

    while(true){
        //запрос к базе

        while(resultSet.next()){
            ar.put(resultSet.getInt(1),new MyObject());
        }

        if(!ar.isEmpty(){
            WeakReference<MyHandler> ex = new WeakReference<MyHandler>(new MyHandler(ar));
            ex.get().start(); ar.clear();
        }

        //затем обновляю строки в базе по массиву, что бы сделать следующую выборку

    } 
}}

public class MyHandler extends Thread{
Map<Integer, MyObject> ar;

public MyHandler(Map<Integer, MyObject> ar){
    this.ar = new HashMap<>(ar);
}

@Override
public void run(){
    //обработка массива
}}
```

Так у меня идет утечка памяти, как можно реализовать по иному?
Создается уйма потоков, не знаю как они по завершению освобождают память.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вы зря вручную создаете треды, есть ThreadPoolExecutor, чтобы брать тред ровно на то время, когда он нужен.

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что есть утечка? Вообще, каждый `Thread` является gc-root, т.е. пока поток жив, объекты, на которые есть ссылки в стеке нельзя собрать. Но если `MyHandler` у вас завершаются, то мап со всем содержимым должен бы собираться. `WeakReference` для локальной переменной, по-моему, не нужен.

Comment: @zRrr в данном случае утечка не из за этого?

Comment: Я не знаю. Если программа вылетает с `OutOfMemoryError`, запустите jvm с ключом `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`, и проанализируйте полученный heap dump в Eclipse MAT или аналогах, там будет видно, какие объекты занимают память. Еще можно к работающей программе подключить `jvisualvm` (входит в jdk) и посмотреть

Comment: Попробуйте протестировать приложение с помощью утилиты VisualVM.

Answer (score 1):

Навскидку, почему

```
Map<Integer, MyObject> ar = new HashMap();
```

создается вне цикла?

Вы его передаете во все хэндлеры, непонятно если он вообще очищается, либо так и содержит все данные, накапливая их.

**Вот как должно быть**

```
while(true){
    //запрос к базе

    Map<Integer, MyObject> ar = new HashMap();
    while(resultSet.next()){
        ar.put(resultSet.getInt(1),new MyObject());
    }

    if(!ar.isEmpty(){
        WeakReference<MyHandler> ex = new WeakReference<MyHandler>(new MyHandler(ar));
        ex.get().start();
    }

    // здесь обрабатывать пока нечего, потому что данные будут готовы асинхронно в MyHandler
    // если все-таки данные нужны здесь, то нужно обрабатывать их синхронно, выкинув MyHandler вообще

}
```

Comment: забыл добавить запись, очищаю его после того, как передал в поток

Comment: `В Java объекты всегда передаются по ссылке, а примитивы - по значению` -- знаете об этом? Все ваши хэндлеры будут иметь пустой набор данных. Потому что у вас он один на всех и вы его чистите сразу же после заполнения.

Comment: Ну примитивы не по значению, а по кешированной ссылке.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Значит код кривой у меня, а вообще необходимо делать ежесекундно из базы запрос на определенные данные, если они есть, то обрабатывать их не затормаживая скорость ежесекундных запросов в базу...не подскажете как элегантно это сделать?) map я в Handler остается тот, который передавался в конструктор this.ar = new HashMap<>(ar);

Comment: Если обработка не будет поспевать за поступлением данных, то приложение в любом случае рано или поздно вывалится в `OutOfMemoty`. Тогда какой смысл ежесекундных выборок? Выбирайте тогда, когда готовы обработать.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, что такое `кешированная ссылка` в контексте JVM? Можно ссылку?

Comment: Все примитивы имеют кешированные ссылки, примитив int 4 и примитив int 4 имеют одинаковые ссылки, поэтому их можно сравнивать. Я этого не делал, но можно попробовать обернуть примитив в Object и использовать toString, в итоге ссылочку. Или попробовать пойти буквально низкоуровневыми фитчами...